# Automatic scroll up after poping jQuery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have jQuery modal popping after user clicks on a icon in the list. List can be huge, so user must scroll down to see full list.
When I click on the icon, modal pops in middle of that screen, and then my browser scrolls up to top of the page.

How can I prevent browser from scrolling up?

HTML

```
<div class="lista">
    <table class="table3">
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($predmeti as $obj){
             ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#" onClick="popModal();"><img src="link"></a>
            </tr>
             <?php   
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

js / jQuery

```
function popModal(){
    $( "#foo" ).dialog({
      open: function ( event, ui) { /* some code */ }, 
      resizable: false,
      height:230,
      width: 230,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Change": function() { /* some code */},
        "Close": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }

    });
}
```

And I have foo div block to show data.

Comment: event.preventDefault(); did the work. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out 2 ways of fixing this.

1st:

Added `event.preventDefault();` to the popModal(); function.

2nd:

Added `onclick = "popModal(); return false;"` to the HTML part of calling function.
Credit goes to morodeer.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

As you have `<a href="#">`, it jumps to `#` anchor. To prevent it in jQuery, you should put `return false;` in the end of `onclick` event, which is in your case `function popModal()`.

So this code should work:

```
function popModal(){
  $( "#foo" ).dialog({
    open: function ( event, ui) { /* some code */ }, 
    resizable: false,
    height:230,
    width: 230,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Change": function() { /* some code */},
      "Close": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
return false;
}
```

For plain JS implementation of preventing default action (like jumping to anchor) just google for event.preventDefault .

Comment: Tried, didn't work. But I fixed it with adding  event.preventDefault(); at the end.

Comment: Maybe `onclick="return popModal()"` or `onclick = "popModal(); return false;"` should work then.